# RoR: redirecting user after registration with devise and cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan

I have devise and cancan set up and I'm having trouble redirecting users to a certain page after registration.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    "http://google.com"
  end
end
```

then in my routes:

```
  authenticated :user do
    root :to => "dashboard#show"
  end
```

Now when I sign up a user, it just gets directed to the dashboard#show. I'm trying to make it go to google.com, but it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong? Or is there another way to redirect users after signing up when using CanCan?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have look on the links given below.

[Rails 3 and Devise: Redirecting to page following signup (confirmable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463012/rails-3-and-devise-redirecting-to-page-following-signup-confirmable)

[overriding devise after_sign_up_path_for not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003347/overiding-devise-after-sign-up-path-for-not-working)

[How-to: Devise after_sign_up_redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566103/how-to-devise-after-sign-up-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Devise Wiki -> [How To: Redirect to a specific page on successful sign up (registration)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29)

Answer (score 0):

You add to your `application_controller.rb`

```
 def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   "http://google.com"
 end
```

source : [redirec_to external_url](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to)

Or you can use certain external link on route looks like

```
# in `config/routes.rb` :

match "/google" => redirect("http://google.com"), :as => :google

# in `registrations_controller.rb` :

def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   google_path
end
```

If you are using Devise's confirmations (the user is not activated after they sign up), you can use `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` method.

```
# controllers/registrations_controller.rb

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController


  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    "http://google.com"
  end

end
```